# GCM PHP get message status

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing a GCM server communication using PHP. I have implemented the code in PHP and able to send the messages successfully to the device. But when the device isn't connected to network the message is lying in the server. The PHP is getting a success response. When the device network is turned on the message is getting actually sent to the device.

My question is that is there a way that I can get back from the GCM server or ping GCM server to know the status of the message_id I sent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Upstream Messages. It has a delivery receipt requested feature. Check out this documentation here : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#receipts

Comment: Can we use upstream messages using http communication and not using CCS?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the simple HTTP communication with the GCM server, your only way to know if the app received a message is to put some message identifier in the message payload (not the message identifier returned by GCM server, since you can't access that in the app), and to send that message identifier from your app to your server when the message is received.